# Work-around for Cross-origin image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy

Tags: three.js

Trying to load images from an API for use as a texture; running into `Cross-origin image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy`.

Does anyone have this working?

jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/calvintennant/AQA97/2/

Possibly related issue: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/687

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to enable CORS support where the images are hosted. Google Cloud Storage and Amazon S3 both support this.

Comment: Seems like S3 claims to support this, but doesn't deliver this fully (yet, though they are working on this): https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=112772